# Passing configuration to a CommonJS module

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection, reactjs

**Source code**

https://gist.github.com/joecritch/3ef1a1ffc8c281eb74be

**Issue**

I have an architectural with JavaScript. I've written a CommonJS module, but it's tightly coupled to an internal configuration object (see `var config`). **I want to abstract this configuration, so that the module can be reused in other environments/projects**.

**Background**

The module is used for API communication, namely just user authentication currently. It's token based, for which I will keep track of the token expiration, allowing for all state to be client-side. The reason for EventEmitter and AppDispatcher is because it's based on the "flux" architecture by Facebook.

--

Any directions on this would be awesome. I've considered dependency injection, but I don't quite understand how this would apply?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _abstract this configuration_ ? Do you want to have this object behind an interface and the config values stored somewhere else? If yes, where?

Comment: I'm open to ideas on implementation for the configuration object. The important thing is that APIService needs to be required from arbitrary project locations, persisting the configuration.

Comment: `var config = require('config')`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of libraries to manage configuration out there but I prefer to keep it simple:

**config/index.js**

```
var config = {
  facebook: {
    key: 'foo',
    secret: 'bar'
  }
}

try {
    require('./' + (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'))(config)
} catch (e) {
}

module.exports = config
```

**config/production.js**

```
var configure = function(config) {
  config.facebook.secret = 'super secret'
}

module.exports = configure
```

**app.js**

```
var config = require('./config')
```

Comment: Thanks simenbrekken. So you would require the `config` module directly from the potentially external module (my `APIService`)? I feel like this means the structure of an app would be quite opinionated, and may restrict other implementations, but it works well for my current case.